# Will making call or sms requests via the Twilio C# libraries always use HTTPS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twilio, twilio-api

So I have some code that makes a call to the Twilio web API via the Twilio supplied C#.Net Libraries.

```
private static void SendSMS(Shift_Offer so, Callout co, testdb2Entities5 db)
{

    co.status = CalloutStatus.inprogress;

    string ShMessage = getShiftMessage(so, co, db);
    so.offer_timestamp = DateTime.Now;
    string ServiceSID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    var message = MessageResource.Create
                (
                    body: ShMessage,
                    messagingServiceSid: ServiceSID,
                    to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(RCHStringHelpers.formatPhoneNumber(so.employee_phone_number)),
                    statusCallback: new Uri(TwilioCallBotController.SMSCallBackURL)
                );

    so.status = message.Status.ToString();
    so.twillio_sid = message.Sid;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I send this message request to the through the C# libraries, will it make the request using HTTPS? I'm concerned about sending the SID in plaintext.

Comment: You can install Fiddler or some other HTTP proxy and observe the requests.  Also, nice name.

Comment: Yeah I thought of using fiddler, but I use an app service on azure as my test environment. I don't usually setup my dev environment to send/receive calls from Twilio due to fussing with the firewall every-time I change spots.

Comment: Okay.  I don't use Twilio, but let's see.  I notice in the Twilio docs that every example of the REST client uses HTTPS.  Also, going to http://twilio.com will redirect you to the HTTPS site.  While not a direct answer, we can probably infer that Twilio is committed to using HTTPS everywhere they can. If you want a more concrete answer, you could use ILSpy to decompile the library and search for "http".

Comment: Hmm okay. I just got the IT guy to route 8080 to my dev machine, since I'm the only dev guy around. So I think I can use fiddler and go from there.

Comment: Yup.  The primary difference between HTTP and HTTPS is the SSL/TLS protocol wrapping the HTTP protocol.  In the HTTPS handshake, only the URL is visible in plaintext, everything else is behind the shroud of encryption.  Browsers and servers perform this encryption/decryption transparently and automatically based on the protocol.  After the HTTPS request/response is decrypted, it's now an ordinary HTTP request/response, headers and all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The API is only available over https at the base URL `https://api.twilio.com`. Also, all the officialy Twilio libraries, including the C# one, are setup to use https by default.

Comment: Thanks Phil. That makes sense, but wanted to confirm.

Answer (score -2):

I've developed a Twilio integration for Dell.

They have some source code available here:

https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp

You can see there that they are using HTTP

https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/blob/master/src/Twilio/Http/SystemNetHttpClient.cs.

Here at Dell, I needed to create my own Twilio implementation based on their REST API because of security concerns using HTTP.

Therefore, I highly recommend you to develop by yourself and make sure to use the HTTPS protocol.

Comment: I can see an authorization header being attached to the request though. What makes you say they're not using HTTPS?

Comment: The presence of auth headers isn't related to whether the connection is protected by TLS.

Comment: According to [the Request class](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/blob/46bf3f014c8d02b551e339abf690d5589c40b8e7/src/Twilio/Http/Request.cs#L78), all Twilio requests use "https".  I don't understand this answer.  "You can see here they are using HTTP"  Nowhere in the linked file is HTTP or HTTPS specified as a protocol.  `HttpClient` does both.

Comment: I do not think this answer is correct.  It may have been at one time in the past, but I don't think it is now.  I downloaded the repository and searched for `"http`.  This brings back *only* results containing `"https://`.

Comment: Good to know on the former (I had assumed that System.Net.Http would turn on TLS if you supply an authorization header).

Also good to know on the latter. I will confirm with fiddler.